# Parsing the output of 'ifconfig' in bash

Tags: bash, parsing

I need to be able to extract the IPv4 mask/prefix length on an interface and represent it in CIDR format. For instance:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:9f:af:5b
          inet addr: 20.30.40.50  Bcast:20.30.40.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe9f:af5b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:261023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:76737163 (76.7 MB)  TX bytes:2750807 (2.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:81879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:81879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:8061949 (8.0 MB)  TX bytes:8061949 (8.0 MB)
```

I need to fetch the contents of 'Mask' (255.255.255.0) on eth0 and represent it as '/24'. How do I do this in bash?

Or is there another way to obtain the information I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: `awk` is good for tasks like this. What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry if this a silly question but what do you mean represent it as '/24'

Comment: `'ifconfig | awk '/Mask/ && !seen {print $4;seen=1}'`

Comment: @Jidder That's [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation.

Comment: Just to be completely clear, the expected output is `20.30.40.0/24`. A sloppy approximation would be `20.30.40.50/24`.

Comment: @Downvoter: Appreciate a reason for downvoting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
echo -n /;ip -4 addr | awk '/eth0/ { getline; {print $2} }' | cut -f2 -d/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script like this to parse `ifconfig` output and print `mask` value:

```
ifconfig | awk -F 'Mask:' '/Mask/ && !/127\.0\.0\.1/{print $2 "/24"}'
255.255.255.0/24
```

Comment: He asks for the contents of Mask though, this just appears to be code copied from somewhere for the ip address ?

Comment: Not copied but my own way of printing IP address. Since OP didn't provide any expected output I showed him a way to parse the output using awk.

Comment: I didnt mean copied from someone else, i just meant it looked like youd copied it from a script or something, doesnt he say at the bottom he wants the contents of mask ?

Comment: @Downvoter: I would really appreciate a comment for the reason of down vote.

Comment: @Jidder: I know it very well that you didn't since you showed courtesy of expressing your views by comments. It is these down votes without comments that don't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ip command.

```
ip -4 a | grep 'inet' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to extract Mask using sed:

```
ifconfig eth0|sed -n "s|.*Mask:\(.*\)|\1|p"
```